# How to put different type of function pointer into one container(vector...)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

There are some functions that have different return types, if there has a method to put the pointers of these functions into one `vector` or `array`, or other containers?

```
    void f1();
    int f2();
    char f3();
```

**edited:** another demo code, maybe it is more concrete.

```
class Base 
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()=default;

};

class D1 : public Base
{
public:
    void show()
    {  
        cout << "D1::show()" << endl;
    }

};

class D2 : public Base
{
public:
    void show()
    {  
        cout << "D2::show()" << endl;
    }

};

class D3 : public Base
{
public:
    void show()
    {  
        cout << "D3::show()" << endl;
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    D1* f0()
    {
        cout << "f0" << endl;
        return &d1;
    }
    D2* f1()
    {
        cout << "f1" << endl;
        return &d2;
    }
    D3* f2()
    {   
        cout << "f2" << endl;
        return &d3;

    }

private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    D3 d3;
};


class B
{
public:
    void f(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            obj_a.f0();
        else if (n == 1)
            obj_a.f1();
        else if (n == 2)    
            obj_a.f2();       
    }
private:
    A obj_a;
};
```

I need to implement the function `B::f(int n)`, and don't want to use many `if-else`. In function `B::f(int n)`, it will call a function depend on the value of `n`,if I can put this funtions into a vector or array and call these functions by `v[n]()`?

Comment: You can use std::variant

Comment: Runtime polymorphism and an `int` to select a method, that would be a reason to recheck some overall design choices.

Comment: you mean it  is not a right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: You still did not provide an example where you are able to handle the different return types. It is quite easy to store different functions which return different types. But in which case such a scenario makes sense? You still can not show us your use case. Is it possible that you think in a technical solution which did not fit to your real problem? As your code makes no sense and we got no further info, the question stays unclear... Vote to close please!

Comment: I want to call these functions by a `int` index, using `int` to select a function. otherwise I have to use `if-else` to check the int number `n`, and chose a function. these functions are orderd.

Comment: @FLYFLY But how are you planning to make use of the return values of these functions? Your only example ignores them, so they might as well return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Updated exmaple using compile time polymorpism (specialization of code through templates) and an interface for starting a function call independent of the return type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define an interface we can call regardless of the return type

struct task_itf
{
    virtual ~task_itf() = default;
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
protected:
    task_itf() = default;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// define a task for functions with a return type

template<typename retval_t>
struct task :
    public task_itf
{
public:
    task(std::function<retval_t()> fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    };

    retval_t& get() 
    {
        return m_result;
    }

    void operator()() override
    {
        m_result = m_fn();
    }

private:
    std::function<retval_t()> m_fn;
    retval_t m_result;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// specialize a task for functions without return type

template<>
struct task<void> :
    public task_itf
{
    task(std::function<void()> fn) :
        m_fn{ fn }
    {
    };

    // for demo purpose, in production code I would get do nothing and return a void
    const char* get() 
    {
        static const char* retval{ "<void>" };
        return retval;
    }

    void operator()() override
    {
        m_fn();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_fn;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void f1() {};
int f2() { return 42; };
char f3() { return 'c'; };

int main()
{
    task<void> task1{ f1 };
    task<int> task2{ f2 };
    task<char> task3{ f3 };

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<task_itf>> tasks{ task1,task2,task3 };

    for (const auto& task : tasks)
    {
        task(); // call the wrapped functions
    }

    std::cout << "result of f1 = " << task1.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << "result of f2 = " << task2.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << "result of f3 = " << task3.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes , I want to use v[0], v[1] ... to call these function

Comment: That's what this code is doing in the for loop, you mean you want to get their return values?

Comment: I just edited the description and added another demo code

Comment: Yes, I need to use the return values for other usage.

Comment: Updated example